# Bootstrap Tab Inside ASP.Net Razor Loop

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have simple bootstrap(3) tabs inside a `div` (`class="example"`).

I have the `div` saved in a Partial view.

I am using `foreach` loop in my Razor view, passing the object to the Partial view and outputting it for each iteration.

How can I simply navigate each `div`'s own tabs without affecting other tabs inside the loop?

**View:-**

```
@foreach (var pbrModel in Model)
{
   @Html.Partial("~/_TestViewPartial.cshtml", pbrModel)
}
```

**Partial View:-**

```
@model PbrViewModel

<div class="example">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use a `for` loop, and append the index of each iteration of the loop to the `id` of the tabs, to give them unique ids. I'll add an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the items in your main view's `Model`, and then use the `i` iterator to make each tab's `id` unique by appending it in the partial view.

You can pass the `i` value as a "model" to the partial view when you iterate.

Like so:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/_TestViewPartial.cshtml", i)
}
```

---

Then in the partial view, you can use the "model" passed to it from your `for` loop - in this case as an `int` type, so it can print the value into the ids accordingly.

Like so:

```
@model int

<div class="example">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home@Model" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile@Model" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages@Model" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings@Model" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home@Model">...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile@Model">...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages@Model">...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings@Model">...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Much like my previous (before this edit) answer, passing the `i` variable to each iteration ensures the `id`s are unique.

Unfortunately, with this way you will not be able to access any properties of the main view's `Model`, as you are only passing the `int` to the Partial view, and nothing else *(I explain more below)*.

---

A couple of notes to think about:

- Your path to the partial doesn't need to be "relatively absolute". In that, I mean you can just use `"_TestViewPartial.cshtml"` as the first argument (omitting the "~/")
- *If* you do wish to access properties of your main view's `pbrModel`s inside the partial, you will need to pass these to the partial (as per your OP, with `PbrViewModel` as the `@model` type) and I would suggest adding a unique indexer property to that type, if possible - so you can then print this in the `id`/`href` of the elements within your partial view, like in my example; just use `@model.MyUniqueIDProperty` or whatever friendly name you have for it
- *THINK* - Do you really need a separate partial view for this? If you're reusing the code elsewhere, then yes. If it's solely for the purpose of the page, then no; I would defer to having the code in the main view's code - you would then still be able to access the main `Model` of the page, if you need to get properties from the `PbrViewModel`s using the indexer you're at (`Model[i]`)

Any questions, just ask.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: sorry that, my code should have mentioned more precisely that, my iterating div is inside another partial view, I have updated my sample code, please advise based on this scenario. thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, easy enough to adapt to the updated question. Will edit my answer

Comment: Updated my answer, with a few important points to think about, too. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You're welcome @ShuvoAmin - don't forget to come back and upvote the answer if you found it helpful, when you have enough reputation. And lastly - welcome to SO! Happy coding! :)